# show moving image form one div to other div in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript

When I click on image it will go in other div but when it goes in other div it should be display moving image from div A to div B
Can any one tried this ?

Comment: Where's the code and what have you tried so far?

Comment: share a fiddle or your code you have tried so far ?

Comment: Check This=>
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25895855/moving-an-image-from-one-div-to-another-div-with-css-as-part-of-a-javascript

Answer (score 0):

I did this just for fun: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Arg0n/bcupjz5r/3/)

HTML

```
<div class="blue">
  <img src="http://fakeimg.pl/200/" class="move-me" />
  <img src="http://fakeimg.pl/200/" class="move-me" />
  <img src="http://fakeimg.pl/200/" class="move-me" />
</div>
<div class="green"></div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).on('click', '.move-me', function(){
  var $img = $(this);
  var x1 = $img.position().left;
  var y1 = $img.position().top;
  var $imgCloned1 = $img.clone().css("visibility", "hidden");
  var $imgCloned2 = $imgCloned1.clone();
  $imgCloned2.insertAfter($img);
  $(".green").append($img);
  var x2 = $img.position().left;
  var y2 = $img.position().top;
  $img.css({'position':'absolute', 'left': x1 + 'px', 'top': y1 + 'px'});
  $imgCloned1.appendTo(".green");
  $img.animate({'left': x2, 'top': y2 + 'px'}, 1000, function() {
    $img.css({'position':'', 'left': '', 'top': ''});
    $img.removeClass("move-me");
    $imgCloned1.remove();
    $imgCloned2.remove();
  });
});
```

CSS

```
.blue, .green {
  min-height: 200px;
  margin: 30px
}

.blue {
  background: skyblue;
}

.green {
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following script in order to move one image from one position to another based on the position of a "target" div.

- When you click on the image, image move to "target" div.
- When click on yellow box, you can change position of "target" div and on click on image you can preposition image again.

```js
(function(window) {
  var _app = {
    elmImage: null,
    elmTarget: null,
    imageGeometry: null,
    targetGeometry: null,
    getDomImage: function() {
      this.elmImage = document.getElementById('image');
    },
    getDomSourceGeometry: function() {
      this.imageGeometry = this.elmImage.getBoundingClientRect();
    },
    getDomtarget: function() {
      this.elmTarget = document.getElementById('target');
    },
    getDomTargetGeometry: function() {
      this.targetGeometry = this.elmTarget.getBoundingClientRect();
    },
    animate: function() {
      var top = this.targetGeometry.top + 'px',
        left = this.targetGeometry.left + 'px';
      $(this.elmImage).animate({
        top: top,
        left: left
      });
    },
    listenImageClick: function() {
      $(this.elmImage).click(function() {
        _app.animate();
      });
    },
    listenChangeTarget: function() {
      $('#targetChange').click(function() {
        this.changeTargetPosition();
      }.bind(this));
    },
    changeTargetPosition: function() {
      $(this.elmTarget).css({
        top: '100px',
        left: '50px'
      });
      this.logic();
    },
    logic: function() {
      _app.getDomImage();
      _app.getDomSourceGeometry();
      _app.getDomtarget();
      _app.getDomTargetGeometry();
    }
  };
  this.elmImage = null;
  $(document).ready(function() {
    _app.logic();
    _app.listenImageClick();
    _app.listenChangeTarget();
  });
})(window);
```

```css
#target {
  position: absolute;
  top: 300px;
  left: 300px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: darkgray;
}

#image {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

#targetChange {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="target"></div>
<img id="image" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">
<div id="targetChange"> Click here to change position target div</div>
```